# Undefined variable: cellspacingx ( Codeigniter & tcpdf )

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, tcpdf

Im using codeigniter but I have a problem when i want to convert my data to pdf using tcpdf

this is the problem :

[image: Picture problem]

can you help me ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had non-valid TABLE tag (missing quote sign). when validating it, the error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

replace cellspacingx by @cellspacingx, this notice display just in developer envirement

Comment: in tcppdf.php I found $cellspacingx , how i change this variable into @cellspacingx ??

Answer (score 0):

Go to file tcpdf/tcpdf.php and on line 18114 replace `$cellspacingx` with `@$cellspacingx`.

Other way can be turn off notices error reporting in your controller using `error_reporting(E_ERROR);`